# Badge Suggestion: One Hit Wonder

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Check out this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/users/504952/carlo-bos
His only activity ever, is answering a single question, which has net him almost 2500 points.

The One Hit Wonder could be, answered a question with over 100 points, with no other answers over 3 points.

Also note the he decided to post his answer a year after Jon Skeet.  Which maybe is a new badge suggestion by its self, "Smarter Than Jon Skeet".

Comment: Am I the only one now tempted to downvote that one-line code-only answer with no explanation?

Comment: @Wooble apparently, it was exactly what people needed...  A lot of people...

Comment: Is a user who has only one answer and is no longer active, really going to care about getting a badge?

Comment: It's better to think up useful badges and *then* consider cute names for them than the other way around.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply put, no.

Badges are supposed to reward behavior or for using certain features of the site.

This badge would encourage, or at least reward, a person to post a single answer, and never come back.  Or worse, create multiple accounts to ask a single question in the hopes of earning the badge.

I don't see this as a badge worth implementing.

Comment: `Badges are supposed to reward behavior or for using certain features of the site` - so... what does Tumbleweed reward?

Comment: @Mike - yeah... I've never figured that one out.  Maybe an incentive to keep using the site?  "Sorry no one looked at your question, here's a badge, please stick around".

Comment: Ah, the pitty badge. ;)

Comment: @Mike: Tenacity. Asking and answering low-frequency tag questions. All those questions by new users in new areas where you are not (yet) likely to get upvotes. That said, I've seen Tenacious and Unsung Hero awarded to b*sterds who's answers are so condescending you never would give them an upvote, but where the answer was technically correct so it got accepted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're thinking the necromancy badge, or whatever it is.  Tumbleweed is for asking a *question* that nobody even views.

Comment: @Servy: No, I was thinking about the companion badges to Tumbleweed; `Tenacious` and `Unsung Hero`. The three cover the same terrain.

Answer (score 10):

Do we want to reward a person who posted one answer and then never came back?

**NO!**

Badges are supposed to reward activity on the sites.

I doubt a user who posted a one good answer and is no longer active is really going to care about receiving a badge.

I am sorry but this badge would be pointless.

Answer (score 2):

**Awards like badges should encourage people in continuous involvement and activity within the community rather than single hit and runs.**

Therefore, my opinion about your suggestion is negative. We don't need to encourage or award such behavior.

And also, the user her/him-self will not care about that badge, would s/he?

Answer (score 2):

In my own opinion, the badge doesn't really makes sense. So in order to get that:

- you need to create an account
- answer a single question
- and wait for how many years to achieve that badge
- once you achieved that badge, you can now continue answering?

I don't think this will be granted.